# TextInputLayout "setText" Function

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout

For EditText fields, there is function "setText" to set default value. However, when it is used for TextInputLayout fields, it shows an error. Is there any equivalent function used for TextInputLayout.

```
TextInputLayout nameItem, amountItem, dateItem;
Button btnSaveUpdate, btnDelete;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_task_desk);

    nameItem = findViewById(R.id.textName);
    amountItem = findViewById(R.id.textAmount);
    dateItem = findViewById(R.id.textDate);

    btnSaveUpdate = findViewById(R.id.btnSaveUpdate);
    btnDelete = findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);

    //get a value from previous page
    nameItem.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("titleItem"));

}
```

Comment: Can you tell us what error message appeared?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/textfield/TextInputEditText

Answer (score 0):

you should init

> TextInputEditText

instead of TextInputLayout  and call setText for TextInputEditText .

> TextInputEditText is in the TextInputLayout  view;

```
TextInputEditText nameItem;

nameItem = findViewById(R.id.textName); //textName should be a TextInputEditText  in TextInputLayout  view

nameItem.setText(/* your string */)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
textInputLayout.getEditText().setText("...");
```